# Mongoose queries running twice in async/await

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**Problem**.

I've been trying to research this for a couple weeks, i remember reading somewhere that using `async/await` with mongoose queries for `MongoDB` actaully executes the same query twice, this has become a slight problem in my appliaction as it has grown, i seem to be throwing warnings on my database that i've scanned 10k+ objects but only returned a small number of documents, and i believe this is the reason why, I believe i've setup these queries to run multiple times and id like to restructure the code to keep it from happening, but i cant find what i need to fix this

**I've tried..**

I've looked over the documents from `mongoose` and it talks about queries that return a `thennable` but are not true `Promises`, These queries can be observed but observing them can cause the query to be re-executed

(taken from mongoose documentation):

> Because Queries are also thenables, we can interact with a Query using async/await just as we would interact with a genuine promise, with one key difference: observing the fulfillment value of a genuine promise cannot under any circumstances change that value, but trying to re-observe the value of a Query may cause the Query to be re-executed.

**Where i need Help**

So what i need is help figuring out the difference between what exactly is a query and what is a genuine promise in `mongoose`'s methods. As i would like to attempt to keep from re-running these queries. below is an example of the code i've wrote that according to `MongoDB`'s Atlas, has the largest affect on my problem.

```
import Video from '../../../models/videoModel.js';

/**
 * @description - This function is used to get the recommended videos for a user this is done by running an algorithm that
 *                will get the videos that fall into a certain set of criteria. The criteria is as follows:
 *               - The video is not a livestream
 *               - The video is not a private video
 *               - The video is not a video that the user has already watched
 *               - The video is not a video that the user has already liked
 *               - The video is somewhere between 5 minutes and 30 minutes long
 * @param {number} page - The page number that the user is on
 * @param {number} limit - The number of videos that the user wants to see per page
 * @param {string} sort - The sort order that the user wants to see the videos in
 * @param {Boolean} sample - If this is true, will return a random sample of videos
 *
 * @returns {Array} - Returns an array of videos that meet the criteria
 * @author  - Austin Howard
 * @since   - 1.0.0
 * @version - 1.3.0
 */
export default async (page, limit, sort, key, sample) => {
  try {
    // sort is passed in as a ';' separated string, so we need to split it into an array
    const sortArray = sort.split(';');
    const keyword = key
      ? {
          videoTitle: {
            $regex: key,
            $options: 'i',
          },
        }
      : {};
    const videos = await Video.aggregate([
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'users',
          localField: 'user',
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'user',
          pipeline: [
            {
              $project: {
                profileImageUrl: 1,
                username: 1,
                hiddenChannel: 1,
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      },
      { $unwind: { path: '$user', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
      {
        $match: {
          // we want to get only the videos that are not private
          // and videos that have a status of 'finished'
          ...keyword,
          isPublic: true,
          status: 'finished',
          isLivePro: false,
          'user.hiddenChannel': false,
          // find the videos that have a duration of 5 minutes to 30 minutes
          duration: {
            $gte: 300,
            $lte: 3600,
          },
        },
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'profiles',
          localField: 'user._id',
          foreignField: 'user',
          as: 'profile',
        },
      },
      {
        $setWindowFields: {
          output: { totalCount: { $count: {} } },
        },
      },
      // count the amount of views in the views array
      {
        $addFields: {
          viewCount: {
            $cond: {
              if: { $isArray: '$views' },
              then: { $size: '$views' },
              else: 0,
            },
          },
        },
      },
      // we need to unwind the user and profile arrays because they are returned as arrays
      { $unwind: { path: '$profile', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
      // we want a random sample of videos, only if the page is not passed in
      // conditionally add the sample stage to the pipeline
      ...(sample
        ? [
            {
              $sample: { size: limit },
            },
          ]
        // creates a empty stage in the aggregation, so it wont return a sampling
        : []),

      { $sort: { [sortArray[0]]: sortArray[1] === 'asc' ? -1 : 1 } },
      // skip, only if the page is passed in
      { $skip: (page - 1) * limit },
      { $limit: Number(limit) },
    ]);

    return videos;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    throw new Error(error);
  }
};
```

This is where i believe most of my issues lay, because im unsure if im using the `async/await` correctly. I know a possible alternative to this would be using the callback methods on the fucntions (i.e., `Video.aggregate([...], (err, results) => {})`) but im not sure thats the best path to take either, as according to the same docs, that i pulled the qoute from, they seem to indicate this isnt the best practice for querying the database. However it also could be something im doing in my `aggregation` stages that's causing the issue, though im not sure what would cause it to scan 100k+ documents, when my database as a total of all collections only has about 5k documents.

Comment: "*using async/await with mongoose queries for MongoDB actaully executes the same query twice*" - no, it does not. "*i remember reading somewhere*" - please give a proper reference for this bold claim.

Comment: @Bergi if i knew where i read it, it would be referenced. the whole point of this query is im trying to ascertain why im getting all these alerts from `MongoDB`, as i stated in my question, of all the documents in my database, it only has a total of about 5k documents between all tables, if the queries are re-executing, this would give a probable cause as to why im getting these alerts.

Comment: It doesn't need to be a reference to where you read it originally. It could be to any article explaining this, or you could show your own research to demonstrate that it actually executes anything twice. Without some further evidence, we'll just dismiss the premise of the question as wrong.

Comment: "*if the queries are re-executing, this would give a probable cause*" - running twice does not explain 100k scanned documents when the collection has 5k documents. It would explain 10k scanned documents.

Comment: "*the whole point of this que[stion] is im trying to ascertain why im getting all these alerts*" - then please show us the exact alert message you are receiving, and adjust the title of your question to ask about that, instead of guessing that it must have something to do with `async`/`await`.

Comment: @Bergi i've looked at specific documentation that pertains to the alerts, nothing comes back as useful. all i get is a run around, that somehow the queries arent optimized, but im unable to ascertain what about the specific queries are not optimized, in this case, i know that this query is scanning about 1k documents and returning 5 everytime its ran. (this is partly by design as these are `recommended`). In all of my research i've been unable to find anything to help optimize the query further at this time. i read breifly that it *could* be `async/await` which is the point of this question.

Comment: @Bergi if you've nothing useful to add that would help, you could move on. i was hoping the developer community at large might know of a better way to handle these queries.

Comment: @Bergi, otherwise here is the alert from Mongo `Query Targeting: Scanned Objects / Returned has gone above 10000` with a current value of `18k+` (i just received this alert 5 minutes ago, ill get them all day, and usually they top out around 100k